silencing Blender output using Python
I have a python app that imports bpy as a module.  I am trying to silence all the Blender console outputs so that outputs like
Fra:1 Mem:7.99M (19.13M, Peak 27.65M) | Scene, Part 243-256
Fra:1 Mem:7.99M (19.16M, Peak 27.65M) | Scene, Part 244-256

doesn't flood the console and interfere with my own console output.
So far I've tried a few solutions I found but most of them seems to leave stdout in a weird state that causes certain errors. Here is my current code that works at silencing render.render() but throws an exception during save_as_mainfile() for some reason.
Is there anyway I can go about silencing Blender completely without any side effects?
The crash I am experiencing is only present on Windows. It seems supressing the stdout is much more reliable on Mac and Linux.
import os
import bpy

class SuppressOutput:
    def __init__(self):
        self.duplicate_stdout_fd: int | None = None

    def __enter__(self):
        sys.stdout.flush()
        self.duplicate_stdout_fd = os.dup(sys.stdout.fileno())
        null_fd = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_WRONLY)
        os.dup2(null_fd, sys.stdout.fileno())
        os.close(null_fd)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        sys.stdout.flush()
        os.dup2(self.duplicate_stdout_fd, sys.stdout.fileno())
        os.close(self.duplicate_stdout_fd)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hello")
    print("Blender Version is: ", bpy.app.version_string)

    with SuppressOutput():
        # comment out the save_as_mainfile() line to make this script work
        bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath="//test.blend")
        bpy.ops.render.render()

    print("Goodbye")



I don't think that's it's a good idea to hijack the console. Imagine every script trying that. Why don't you just write the output of your script to a file?

The logging module is available in the Blender's Python version. Just saying ...

To be clear, this is not for a Blender addon. It's an app that calls Blender to do some work. My app is console based, so I agree with you that what the console shows should be strictly controlled. Which is why I only want MY app to output to it and have all Blender outputs be silenced.   I am already logging stuff, but a lot of Blender's output (like the rendering status) is being emitted at the C level.

stdout=subprocess.PIPE
If the app calls Blender with something like process = subprocess.Popen, you just capture all the output from the process with stdout=subprocess.PIPE and read it from process.stdout and print in the main process conditionally.
socket
You can also suppress all the output from the sub-process with stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL and instead create a socket connection and write to the socket from within the sub-process.
os.dup2
If you need to capture the stdout from within the same interpreter and from the same file descriptor the Blender is currently printing to you need to use low-level functions to create and override the file descriptors. You can redirect the stdout only to low-level file-like objects such as os.pipe or os.devnull or a file on disk.
Windows
On Windows Python 3.6 - 3.10 does some handling that caches sys.stdout.buffer and exhibit random erroneous behavior. It is a Python bug: bpo-30555: Fix WindowsConsoleIO errors in the presence of fd redirection. The fix was not backported. sys.stdout needs to be recreated both times after os.dup2. This has implications but for the usage such as the OP's as a throwaway instance of Blender for background jobs will suffice.
Handling like pytest's _windowsconsoleio_workaround
Capture_Stdout
import io
import os
import queue
import sys
import threading
import ctypes
import traceback


class Capture_Output:

    _std_output_name: str


    def __init__(self, is_dummy = False, use_set_other = True):
        self.lines = queue.Queue()
        self.is_dummy = is_dummy
        self.use_set_other = use_set_other


    def __enter__(self):

        if self.is_dummy:
            return self

        self.flush()


        std_output: io.TextIOWrapper = getattr(sys, self._std_output_name)

        self.prev_std_output = std_output

        self.file_descriptor = std_output.fileno()

        self.file_descriptor_copy = os.dup(self.file_descriptor)

        self.pipe_read_fileno, self.pipe_write_fileno = os.pipe()

        self.pipe_reading = threading.Thread(target=self.read_pipe)
        self.read_pipe_textwrapper = os.fdopen(self.pipe_read_fileno, encoding='utf-8')
        self.pipe_reading.start()

        os.dup2(self.pipe_write_fileno, self.file_descriptor)
        self.write_pipe_textwrapper = os.fdopen(self.pipe_write_fileno, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
        setattr(sys, self._std_output_name, self.write_pipe_textwrapper)

        if self.use_set_other:
            self.set_other(self.prev_std_output, self.write_pipe_textwrapper)

        return self


    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, _traceback):

        if self.is_dummy:
            return

        ctypes_flush_error, sys_flush_error = self.flush()


        os.dup2(self.file_descriptor_copy, self.file_descriptor)

        if self.do_need_recreate_windows_output():
            prev_std_output = self.copy_text_io_wrapper(self.file_descriptor, self.prev_std_output)
        else:
            prev_std_output = self.prev_std_output

        setattr(sys, self._std_output_name, prev_std_output)
        if self.use_set_other:
            self.set_other(self.write_pipe_textwrapper, prev_std_output)


        self.write_pipe_textwrapper.close()
        self.pipe_reading.join()
        self.read_pipe_textwrapper.close()

        if ctypes_flush_error is not None:
            print(ctypes_flush_error, file = sys.stderr)

        if sys_flush_error is not None:
            print(sys_flush_error, file = sys.stderr)

        os.close(self.file_descriptor_copy)


    def flush(self):
        """
        Theoretically `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` as an environment variable can be used instead.

        Use `flush=True` for time critical prints.
        """


        try:
            if os.name == 'nt':
                lib = ctypes.CDLL('api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll')
            else:
                lib = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6')  # not tested

            lib.fflush(None)

        except Exception as e:
            ctypes_flush_error = traceback.format_exc()
        else:
            ctypes_flush_error = None


        try:
            getattr(sys, self._std_output_name).flush()
        except Exception as e:
            sys_flush_error = traceback.format_exc()
        else:
            sys_flush_error = None


        return ctypes_flush_error, sys_flush_error


    def read_pipe(self):
        for line in self.read_pipe_textwrapper:
            self.lines.put_nowait(line)


    def copy_text_io_wrapper(self, fd: int, prev: io.TextIOWrapper):
        return io.TextIOWrapper(
            os.fdopen(fd, 'wb', -1 if hasattr(prev.buffer, 'raw') else 0),
            prev.encoding,
            prev.errors,
            prev.newlines,
            prev.line_buffering,
        )


    def do_need_recreate_windows_output(self):
        """
        bpo-30555: Fix WindowsConsoleIO errors in the presence of fd redirection
        https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/1927
        https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/changelog.html#id150
        """

        if os.name != 'nt':
            return False

        current_python_version = (sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor)

        if current_python_version >= (3, 10):
            return False

        if current_python_version < (3, 6):
            return False

        if not hasattr(self.prev_std_output, 'buffer'):
            return False

        if hasattr(self.prev_std_output.buffer, 'raw'):
            buffer = self.prev_std_output.buffer.raw
        else:
            buffer = self.prev_std_output.buffer

        if not isinstance(buffer, io._WindowsConsoleIO):
            return False

        return True


    def set_other(self, prev_output, output):
        """ Replace other output targets. Patch this function if needed. """

        import logging

        for logger in logging.root.manager.loggerDict.values():
            for handler in getattr(logger, 'handlers', ()):
                if hasattr(handler, 'stream'):
                    if handler.stream is prev_output:
                        handler.stream = output


class Capture_Stdout(Capture_Output):
    _std_output_name = 'stdout'

class Capture_Stderr(Capture_Output):
    _std_output_name = 'stderr'

Tests
import os
import sys
import time

print('=' * 80)
print("Hello")
print("Python Version is: ", sys.version_info)


def is_in_blender():

    if os.environ.get('I_AM_NOT_BLENDER') == 'True':
        return False

    try:
        import bpy
        return bool(bpy.app.version) and bool(bpy.app.binary_path)
    except Exception:
        return False


if is_in_blender():

    import bpy

    print("Blender Version is: ", bpy.app.version_string)
    with Capture_Stdout() as capture:
        print(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d'))

        if not bpy.context.scene.camera:
            camera = bpy.data.objects.new('Camera', bpy.data.cameras.new('Camera'))
            bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(camera)
            bpy.context.scene.camera = camera

        bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
        bpy.context.scene.cycles.samples = 1
        bpy.context.scene.cycles.use_denoising = False
        bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = 64
        bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = 64

        bpy.ops.render.render()

        bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=os.path.join(bpy.app.tempdir, 'some.blend'), copy=True)

    print(capture.lines.queue)


for i in range(1000):

    with Capture_Stdout() as capture:
        capture.lines.put_nowait(i)
        print(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d'))
        print('hello')
        time.sleep(0.0001)
        print('world')
        print('world')
        print('world')
        print('world')
        with Capture_Stdout() as capture2:
            time.sleep(0.0001)
            print('world')
            print('world')
            print('world')
            print('world')
        print(capture2.lines.queue)
        time.sleep(0.0001)
        print('world')
        print('world')
        print('world')
        print('world')
        time.sleep(0.0001)

    try:
        print(capture.lines.queue)
    except Exception:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)
        print(_, file=sys.stderr)
        break

print("Goodbye")

Possible output
C:\Users\user>blender -b --factory-startup C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\blender_a20660\some.blend --python-text "Text"
Blender 3.1.2 (hash cc66d1020c3b built 2022-03-31 23:39:57)
Read blend: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\blender_a20660\some.blend
================================================================================
Hello
Blender Version is:  3.1.2
['Fra:1 Mem:8.44M (Peak 8.47M) | Time:00:00.00 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Synchronizing object | Cube\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.44M (Peak 8.47M) | Time:00:00.00 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Initializing\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.35M (Peak 8.47M) | Time:00:00.00 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Waiting for render to start\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.35M (Peak 8.47M) | Time:00:00.00 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Loading render kernels (may take a few minutes the first time)\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.35M (Peak 8.47M) | Time:00:00.00 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Scene\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.35M (Peak 8.47M) | Time:00:00.00 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Shaders\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.85M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Procedurals\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.85M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Background\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.85M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Camera\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.85M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Meshes Flags\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.85M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Objects\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.85M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Objects | Copying Transformations to device\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.85M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Objects | Applying Static Transformations\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.85M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Particle Systems\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.85M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Particle Systems | Copying Particles to device\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.85M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Meshes\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.86M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Mesh | Computing attributes\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.86M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Mesh | Copying Attributes to device\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.86M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Scene BVH | Building\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.86M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Scene BVH | Building BVH\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.86M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Scene BVH | Building BVH 0%\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.86M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Scene BVH | Copying BVH to device\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.86M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Mesh | Computing normals\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.86M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Mesh | Copying Mesh to device\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.86M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Objects Flags\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.86M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Primitive Offsets\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.86M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Images\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.86M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Camera Volume\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.86M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Lookup Tables\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.86M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.25M, Peak:0.25M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Lights\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.86M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.25M, Peak:0.25M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Lights | Computing distribution\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.86M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.25M, Peak:0.25M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Integrator\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.86M (Peak 8.86M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.26M, Peak:0.26M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Film\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.87M (Peak 9.12M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.01M, Peak:0.26M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Lookup Tables\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.87M (Peak 9.12M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.26M, Peak:0.26M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Baking\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.87M (Peak 9.12M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.26M, Peak:0.26M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Device | Writing constant memory\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:8.87M (Peak 9.12M) | Time:00:00.02 | Mem:0.26M, Peak:0.26M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 0/1\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:222.47M (Peak 317.39M) | Time:00:06.33 | Mem:150.56M, Peak:150.56M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 1/1\n', 'Fra:1 Mem:222.47M (Peak 317.39M) | Time:00:06.33 | Mem:150.56M, Peak:150.56M | Scene, ViewLayer | Finished\n', 'Info: Total files 0 | Changed 0 | Failed 0\n', 'Info: Saved "some.blend"\n', '04:34:27 2024-04-09\n', 'Info: Saved "some.blend"\n']
Goodbye

Blender quit


Kudos for identifying the underlying bug in Python that was causing this. That was the key the to kingdom! I happen to be using Python 3.10 & Blender 4.0. Will upgrade to Py 3.11 & Blender 4.1 wheel asap.

The bug was fixed in Python 3.10.0 beta 1. I don't think Blender is shipped with the beta versions.
